# How do I get desktop environment to work (Slackware 14.2)? xauth: file /root/serverauth.1112 does not exist

Tags: desktop-environment, x-server, slackware

I am newbie to Linux. I have a problem with X server. I just installed Slackware as a second system with windows 11 and I can't start the desktop environment.

Laptop Lenovo IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming

[image]

[image]

/var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    67.153] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.3
Release Date: 2016-04-04
[    67.157] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    67.159] Build Operating System: Slackware 14.2 Slackware Linux Project
[    67.160] Current Operating System: Linux darkstar 4.4.14 #2 SMP Fri Jun 24 13:38:27 CDT 2016 x86_64
[    67.160] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=dev000:\EFI\Slackware\vmlinuz  root=/dev/sda4 vga=normal ro ro
[    67.163] Build Date: 15 April 2016  11:05:21AM
[    67.164]  
[    67.165] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[    67.167]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    67.167] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    67.171] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jul 29 21:04:02 2023
[    67.172] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    67.173] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    67.173] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    67.173] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    67.173] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    67.173] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    67.173] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    67.173] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    67.173] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    67.173] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    67.173] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/local" does not exist.
[    67.173]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    67.173] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/CID" does not exist.
[    67.173]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    67.173] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF,
    /usr/share/fonts/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/cyrillic
[    67.173] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    67.173] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    67.173] (II) Loader magic: 0x808c00
[    67.173] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    67.173]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    67.173]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    67.173]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    67.173]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    67.175] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:3e9b:17aa:3a2e rev 0, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00006000/64
[    67.175] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:1f91:17aa:3a2e rev 161, Mem @ 0xa3000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00005000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    67.175] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    67.175] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    67.175] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    67.177] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.177]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    67.177]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 9.0
[    67.177] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    67.177] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    67.177] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[    67.177] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    67.177] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    67.177] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    67.177] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    67.177] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    67.177] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.177]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 2.99.917
[    67.177]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    67.177]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    67.177] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    67.178] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    67.178] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.178]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.18.3
[    67.178]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    67.178]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    67.178] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    67.178] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[    67.178] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    67.178] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    67.178] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[    67.178] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    67.178] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    67.178] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.178]    compiled for 1.18.0, module version = 2.3.4
[    67.178]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    67.178]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    67.178] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    67.178] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics: 2000-6000
[    67.178] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics: 5100, 6100
[    67.178] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics: 5200, 6200, P6300
[    67.178] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    67.178] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    67.178] (--) using VT number 7

[    67.186] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    67.186] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    67.186] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    67.186] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    67.186] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    67.186] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    67.186] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    67.186] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    67.186] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.186]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    67.186]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    67.186] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    67.186] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    67.187] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    67.187] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.187]    compiled for 1.18.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    67.187]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
[    67.187] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    67.187] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range
[    67.187] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    67.187] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[    67.188] (II) Unloading int10
[    67.188] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[    67.188] (II) Unloading vbe
[    67.188] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    67.188] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    67.188] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    67.188] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    67.188] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    67.188] (EE) 
[    67.197] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: "Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.". Also, are you sure you want to start with Slackware and not a more beginner friendly distribution like, for example Linux Mint.

Comment: @PaulPazderski, I am a junior developer and want to learn advanced linux distros. I've been using Ubuntu for a while

Comment: Then I would recommend you to look into Arch Linux. Slackware is rather old and harder to get help for. Arch Linux has a great [Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) and to quote DistroWatch a "Linux distribution targeted at competent Linux users" so in my opinion a good way to learn more Linux stuff. Also Slackware still uses SysV-Init which is considered deprecated and not used by most other Distros. So you risk to learn stuff which is not applicable on most other Linux systems.

Comment: @PaulPazderski, thanx

Comment: @AGI At the command line, type "startx".  If you want it to boot into the GUI automatically, edit the /etc/inittab file to set the "initdefault" run level to 4.